# Box drawing around the 5-minute candle

Tags: checkbox, flexbox, box, candlesticks

I want to draw a box around a 5-minute candlestick from 8:00 a.m. to 8:05 a.m., so that this box will last for the next three hours and then disappear and reappear on the chart the next day at the same time.
This box should have the ability to edit the time and the ability to edit the color inside and outside the box so that I can use this box at other times.
Thank you

Comment: What technology / framework / language do you use for the candlestick charts?